# Return svg from laravel route?

Tags: php, laravel, svg, routes

I have a function that generates an SVG using EasySVG from custom text and a specified font. I'd like to be able to generate these things using an expressed url such as /customsvg/MYTEXT.svg in laravel.

I know how to add a route that looks like '/customsvg/{text}' but I'm not sure how to actually handle the request in a controller so it spits out the svg data with the proper mime types and in the proper format. (does it need to be base64 encoded for example? It's all path data)

Comment: I was able to determine that just spitting out the result will work but only in so long as the script ends with what resembles an svg filename.  I'd still be curious to know how to force the mime-type from the route.  I'm not entirely sure the laravel well to insert a header on output to an api (REST) call.

Answer (score 0):

(see comments on response by Hodorogea)

I found two ways of handling it.  One in the Route itself since I use a single function call to handle the response and don't need a lot of sanitizing of input.

```
// example right in the routing including a color parameter
Route::get('/colorsvg/{color}/{filename}', function($color,$filename) {
    // remove any .svg suffix on the text
    $custom = preg_replace('/\.svg$/i', '', $filename);
    // add # on the front of numeric RGB values if needed
    if(preg_match('/^[a-fA-F\d]{6}$/', $color)) $color = '#' . $color;

    // function returns array with width, height and svgdata
    $svg = SDKapi::getCustomTextAsSvg($custom, $color);

    return response($svg['svgdata'], 200)
        ->header('Content-Type','image/svg+xml');
});
```

or using a simple controller method (no color in this one)

api.php in routes:

```
Route::get('/customsvg/{filename}', [SVGController::class, 'customsvg']);
```

SVGController.php

```
public function customsvg(Request $request, $filename)
{
    $custom = preg_replace('/\.svg$/i', '', $filename);
    $svg = SDKapi::getCustomTextAsSvg($custom);
    return response($svg['svgdata'], 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First, create a controller and a main method (let's call it index). Make sure that inside the method you also set the proper header of the response. Then, simply return the view which contains the SVG data. Using the example below, you can also paste the text parameter or the generated SVG to the view.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
class SVGController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');            
        $text = $request->input('text');
        $generatedSvg = ...
        return view("customsvg", compact('text', 'generatedSvg'));

    }
}
```

The *customsvg* view should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<!-- Your content goes here. Use the {{$text}} and {{$generatedSvg}} variables as you wish. -->
</svg>
```

Finally, make sure that your rute is properly set up.

```
Route::get('/customsvg/{text}', [SVGController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: will that set a mime type?  I'd like to make sure the server is adding the Content-Type: image/svg+xml -- oh wait, nevermind. Just saw it in your controller.

Comment: Couple things right off - the library I'm using generates the full SVG including some of the content you show. I presume I can just use a blade with {{$generatedSVG}} in it. But I also seem to not be getting anything in $request->input inside the controller. (getting null back from ->input('text'))

Comment: still getting content-type text/html

Comment: shoot, all I needed to do was return response($data)->header('Content-type', 'image/svg+xml');  no need for a view, don't even really need a controller entry if it's not pointing at endusers

Comment: btw, not sure if it's something that changed in laravel, but using a url parameter, I had to specify a variable in the Controller method. e.g. public function index(Request $request, $text) { ... }

I'll post a more detailed version of what i did later.

Comment: I don't mean to be a jerk, but it didn't really help me. If you look at my solution, it's entirely different.  No view, no variables, and the header is attached entirely different. Thus I didn't up-vote your solution as it didn't actually work!